# How to export Maven dependencies or assembly artifact URLs

Tags: maven, jar, export, maven-assembly-plugin

I have a large maven project with several dependencies. There is also an assembly that contains all files I want to deploy - which is not necessarily identical to the dependencies.

My question: How can I generate a textfile that contains all URLs to JAR-files maven usually downloads the artifacts from? Ideally only from those files in the assembly, but of all dependencies would do as well.

**[Update]**
My project consists of a root project which has several artifacts from subprojects and external artifacts as dependencies. All dependencies are either stored in my private Artifactory repository or can at least accessed via it using Artifactory as a proxy. 
When I roll out a new release, I want to be able that the root project writes all it dependencies in a file, suitable that a client can download those dependencies. The client has no idea about repository structures (I'd like to avoid that), so I need full URLs or at least full pathes within an repository root.

Comment: What are you really trying to achieve?

Comment: I want to dynamically update a locally deployed application by comparing a fileset from a local installation with one from an update server.

Comment: If you have project which uses dependencies but producing an assembly which uses different dependencies that's an issue. Furthermore what kind of application do you have? An command line application/swing etc. ? what you need is a kind of update mechanism ...

Comment: The assembly just strips some transitive dependencies that are definitely not required for the application, so I don't consider this an issue. But if it helps solving my problem, I go with all the dependencies.

The application itself is a JavaFX application. It already has an update mechanism, but I want to improve it. I will edit my question to specify the idea behind it.